# SHA-1 com TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, sha1

Estou fazendo um projeto e preciso criptografar uma senha, queria usar o SHA-1, só que não encontrei nenhum lugar para usar com TypeScript, o TS suporta o SHA-1?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693762/angular-2-npm-js-sha1-import 
dá uma olhada ver se te atende.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Achei um link do GitHub onde tem uma classe TS com a SHA-1, foi só adicionar no projeto e adicionar a importação da função sha1 que funcionou corretamente.

Link:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/service-worker/cli/sha1.ts

Para melhor visualização

sha1.ts

```
export function sha1(str: string): string {
  const utf8 = str;
  const words32 = stringToWords32(utf8, Endian.Big);
  return _sha1(words32, utf8.length * 8);
}

export function sha1Binary(buffer: ArrayBuffer): string {
  const words32 = arrayBufferToWords32(buffer, Endian.Big);
  return _sha1(words32, buffer.byteLength * 8);
}

function _sha1(words32: number[], len: number): string {
  const w = new Array(80);
  let [a, b, c, d, e]: number[] = [0x67452301, 0xefcdab89, 0x98badcfe, 
0x10325476, 0xc3d2e1f0];

  words32[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << (24 - len % 32);
  words32[((len + 64 >> 9) << 4) + 15] = len;

  for (let i = 0; i < words32.length; i += 16) {
     const [h0, h1, h2, h3, h4]: number[] = [a, b, c, d, e];

    for (let j = 0; j < 80; j++) {
      if (j < 16) {
       w[j] = words32[i + j];
      } else {
        w[j] = rol32(w[j - 3] ^ w[j - 8] ^ w[j - 14] ^ w[j - 16], 1);
      }

      const [f, k] = fk(j, b, c, d);
      const temp = [rol32(a, 5), f, e, k, w[j]].reduce(add32);
      [e, d, c, b, a] = [d, c, rol32(b, 30), a, temp];
    }

    [a, b, c, d, e] = [add32(a, h0), add32(b, h1), add32(c, h2), add32(d, h3), add32(e, h4)];
  }

  return byteStringToHexString(words32ToByteString([a, b, c, d, e]));
}

function add32(a: number, b: number): number {
  return add32to64(a, b)[1];
}

function add32to64(a: number, b: number): [number, number] {
  const low = (a & 0xffff) + (b & 0xffff);
  const high = (a >>> 16) + (b >>> 16) + (low >>> 16);
  return [high >>> 16, (high << 16) | (low & 0xffff)];
}

function add64([ah, al]: [number, number], [bh, bl]: [number, number]): [number, number] {
  const [carry, l] = add32to64(al, bl);
  const h = add32(add32(ah, bh), carry);
  return [h, l];
}

function sub32(a: number, b: number): number {
  const low = (a & 0xffff) - (b & 0xffff);
  const high = (a >> 16) - (b >> 16) + (low >> 16);
  return (high << 16) | (low & 0xffff);
}

// Rotate a 32b number left `count` position
function rol32(a: number, count: number): number {
   return (a << count) | (a >>> (32 - count));
}

// Rotate a 64b number left `count` position
function rol64([hi, lo]: [number, number], count: number): [number, number] {
  const h = (hi << count) | (lo >>> (32 - count));
  const l = (lo << count) | (hi >>> (32 - count));
  return [h, l];
}

enum Endian {
  Little,
  Big,
}

function fk(index: number, b: number, c: number, d: number): [number, number] {
  if (index < 20) {
    return [(b & c) | (~b & d), 0x5a827999];
  }

  if (index < 40) {
    return [b ^ c ^ d, 0x6ed9eba1];
  }

  if (index < 60) {
     return [(b & c) | (b & d) | (c & d), 0x8f1bbcdc];
  }

  return [b ^ c ^ d, 0xca62c1d6];
}


function stringToWords32(str: string, endian: Endian): number[] {
  const words32 = Array((str.length + 3) >>> 2);

  for (let i = 0; i < words32.length; i++) {
    words32[i] = wordAt(str, i * 4, endian);
  }

  return words32;
}

function arrayBufferToWords32(buffer: ArrayBuffer, endian: Endian): number[] {
  const words32 = Array((buffer.byteLength + 3) >>> 2);
  const view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  for (let i = 0; i < words32.length; i++) {
    words32[i] = wordAt(view, i * 4, endian);
  }
  return words32;
}

function byteAt(str: string | Uint8Array, index: number): number {
  if (typeof str === 'string') {
    return index >= str.length ? 0 : str.charCodeAt(index) & 0xff;
  } else {
    return index >= str.byteLength ? 0 : str[index] & 0xff;
  }
}

function wordAt(str: string | Uint8Array, index: number, endian: Endian): number {
  let word = 0;
  if (endian === Endian.Big) {
     for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      word += byteAt(str, index + i) << (24 - 8 * i);
     }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       word += byteAt(str, index + i) << 8 * i;
    }
  }
  return word;
}

function words32ToByteString(words32: number[]): string {
  return words32.reduce((str, word) => str + word32ToByteString(word), '');
}

function word32ToByteString(word: number): string {
  let str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     str += String.fromCharCode((word >>> 8 * (3 - i)) & 0xff);
  }
  return str;
}

function byteStringToHexString(str: string): string {
  let hex: string = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const b = byteAt(str, i);
    hex += (b >>> 4).toString(16) + (b & 0x0f).toString(16);
  }
  return hex.toLowerCase();
}

// based on http://www.danvk.org/hex2dec.html (JS can not handle more than 
56b)
function byteStringToDecString(str: string): string {
  let decimal = '';
  let toThePower = '1';

  for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    decimal = addBigInt(decimal, numberTimesBigInt(byteAt(str, i), 
toThePower));
    toThePower = numberTimesBigInt(256, toThePower);
  }

  return decimal.split('').reverse().join('');
} 

// x and y decimal, lowest significant digit first
function addBigInt(x: string, y: string): string {
  let sum = '';
  const len = Math.max(x.length, y.length);
  for (let i = 0, carry = 0; i < len || carry; i++) {
    const tmpSum = carry + +(x[i] || 0) + +(y[i] || 0);
    if (tmpSum >= 10) {
      carry = 1;
      sum += tmpSum - 10;
    } else {
      carry = 0;
      sum += tmpSum;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}


function numberTimesBigInt(num: number, b: string): string {
  let product = '';
  let bToThePower = b;
  for (; num !== 0; num = num >>> 1) {
     if (num & 1) product = addBigInt(product, bToThePower);
    bToThePower = addBigInt(bToThePower, bToThePower);
  }
return product;
}
```

No ts do component só adicionei:

```
import { sha1 } from 'sha1';
```

E para usá-la:

```
algumaString = sha1(outraString);
```

Comment: Não seria só dar um import no pacote `@angular/service-worker` ou algo assim (que já é nativo em aplicações angular), me parece que isso ai é nativo (claro que usado na interface cli geralmente, mas deve ser possivel usar em qualquer lugar)? Creio que deve ser possivel importar direto sempre precisar ficar injetando manualmente. Creio que algo assim `import * as sha1 from '@angular/service-worker/cli/sha1'` (não pude testar ainda)

Comment: e provavelmente uso seria `sha1.sha1(...)` ou `sha1.sha1Binary(...)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é instalar esse `npm`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha1

Depois de instalar, vai direto pro componente (pode fazer dentro da função mesmo) e insira duas linhas:

```js
var sha1 = require('sha1');

sha1("message");
```

Se der um `console.log(sha1("message"))` irá ficar assim:

> 6f9b9af3cd6e8b8a73c2cdced37fe9f59226e27d

**EDIT:**
Caso o `require` de algum erro de "Não achei o require no @types/node", você pode declarar uma variável chamada `require` que irá funcionar. Ainda não descobri como resolver esse erro de fato, mas quando descobrir irei editar essa resposta. O modo que falei fica igual ao print abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O padrão da industria e de APIs e enviar a senha ao backend de uma maneira segura com https como um texto normal e fazer a criptografia no backend.

Comment: Então não vou conseguir usar o https por enquanto, por isso decidi usar o SHA-1

Comment: A propósito isso acabou me ajudando a entender certos conceitos sobre web, obrigado!